# Combine data from columns in CSV with nulls based on time stamp

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have multiple CSV files with timestamps and lat long data, with the lat and long in different rows.

```
                 Date_Time_UTC  Latitude_deg  Longitude_deg  
7      2019-04-02 13:39:59.398     28.563535            NaN   
14     2019-04-02 13:39:59.497           NaN      77.085489
```

The expected output is:

```
          Date_Time_UTC  Latitude_deg        Longitude_deg  
7      2019-04-02 13:39     28.563535            77.085489
```

So in case of NaN, it should take the latitude of one observation and the longitude of another observation, provided that both timestamps are in the same minute. The timestamps should be rounded to the nearest minute.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do the rows always alternate?

Comment: yes,
i cleaned all the non relevant rows from the data

Answer (score 0):

*If* your rows always alternate or at least go in pairs, you can group them by their sequential number divided by 2:

```
df_raw = df.reset_index()
df_raw.groupby(df_raw.index // 2).max().set_index('index') 
#                 Date_Time_UTC  Latitude_deg  Longitude_deg
#index                                                      
#14     2019-04-02 13:39:59.497     28.563535      77.085489
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the solution that @ashwin3086 suggested about grouping by the timestamp and the maximum value is what worked best

```
df_grouped = concatenated_df.groupby(['Date_Time_UTC'], as_index=False, sort=False).agg({'Latitude_deg': 'max', 'Longitude_deg' : 'max','FileName' : 'first' })
```

Comment: The paired rows have different datetimes. You cannot group by that column.

Comment: Look in my expected result, part of the processes was to clean the date-time
from  2019-04-02 13:39:59.497 to  2019-04-02 13:39:59

Answer (score -1):

If you have an option to preprocess the files then 
1) Read all csv's and store the data in a list . Basically something to iterate over. You can directly iterate over files also I guess.
2) iterate over the list and see if first 16 characters of timestamp are same .
   If yes , then store the value in a dictionary. Key will be timestamp and values will be latitude and longitude.
3) You can then print the dictionary or use it for further processing.

I am sure you can optimize and reduce the overall operations required. I was just suggesting a process to solve the problem.

Another Option :
Use python pandas and store the data from files.
Then you can do a simple sql to group by timestamp (first 16 characters) and then get Max of latitude and longitude so you have data in one single row.

Comment: Hmm .. Downvoted. Atleast call out why you did that .If you are looking for code ,then I understand.

Comment: not me 
i actually  used you suggestion in my solution